# Search for a specific header, then enter a formula and automatically detect the number of rows to extend it to

Tags: excel, vba

I know that question has already been partially answered but so far I have been unsuccessful in adapting those answers to my problem:

I have made a macro to be run on monthly reports, but it turns out that the number and position of the columns, as well as the number of rows, will be different for every report.

I have included in my macro a code like this:

```
Range("F2").Select  
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _   
"=Blablabla"  
Range("F2").Select  
Dim N As Long  
N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & N), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

This successfully allows me to type a formula in F2 and extend it to as many filled rows as there are in the spreadsheet.

Now, I would like to combine this with a "column finder". So instead of telling the macro to select F2, type the formula and extend it down, I would like to tell the macro to fin the column titled "Location", select the second row (right below the header) and type the formula and extend it to the last filled row.

What would the code for such a thing look like? And do you know if it will make the macro significantly longer to run? (before running the macro, the spreadsheet usually has around 60 columns, all with a different title).

EDIT:
I am having another problem requiring, I believe the same kind of code:
in the reports I run the macro on there is a column "Degree", then several columns ("Major", "Institution" etc) and finally a column "Graduation Date").

Now, I need to change the graduation date according to the degree (to reflect the virtual Bachelor Degree graduation date). So if column "Degree", row 5 says "Associate Degree", I need to add two years to the graduation date in column "Graduation Date", row 5.

And I would like to implement that with the same kind of "header detection" as for the rest of the table (because for this too the columns can move). So I guess I need some kind of code saying:
1) find column "Graduation Date" and insert a column next to it
2) title that new column "B.S. Graduation Date" and put inside a formula until the last filled row.
These two steps I can manage thanks to tigeravatar's code.

What I need help for would be the IF formula saying "IF column "Degree" row 5 says *Associate*, then column "B.S. Graduation Date" must show *date of Degree row 5  +2 Years*", without using the coordinates of the columns, but the "title finder".

Please let me know if that makes sense, and if that is doable.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngLocation As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet    'To set this to a specific sheetname, use Set ws = Sheets("Sheetname")
    Set rngLocation = ws.Rows(1).Find("Location")
    If rngLocation Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'No column with header "Location" found

    lRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row - 1
    With rngLocation.Offset(1).Resize(lRow)
        .Formula = "YourFormula"    'This will automatically autofill
    End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Per comments, updated code looks like this:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngLocation As Range
    Dim rngNewCol As Range
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet    'To set this to a specific sheetname, use Set ws = Sheets("Sheetname")
    Set rngLocation = ws.Rows(1).Find("Location")
    If rngLocation Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'No column with header "Location" found

    'Insert a new column to the right of rngLocation
    rngLocation.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    Set rngNewCol = rngLocation.Offset(, 1)

    'Find last used row in the sheet (subtract one because we won't be including the header row)
    lRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row - 1

    'Populate the new column
    rngNewCol.Value = "Geographic Area"
    With rngNewCol.Offset(1).Resize(lRow)
        .NumberFormat = "General"   'Set column to General format
        .Formula = "YourFormula"    'This will automatically autofill
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer tigeravatar!  
With this code, how (and where in the code) would you insert some lines to add a column?  
>>> so the result of the macro is:  
1) find the column titled "Location"  
2) insert a clumn next to it (on the right)
3) select that new column, make a header ("Geographic Area")
4) in the new column, enter a formula and extend to the last row.

Thank you so much! I usually do not need to be babysitted to that level, but I must admit that I am way out of my comfort zone on Excel right now.

Anthony

Comment: @FacheAnthony Good catch on that, that's what happens when I post code without testing it first ><.  I have updated the answer to include how to change the column's format to General.

Comment: Hello tigeravatar, while playing around with the code you gave me I noticed that this line "If rngLocation Is Nothing Then Exit Sub' could sometimes be a problem as it makes the macro stop when it is not really necessary to stop it. So I was wondering: is there any way to say "if rngLocation Is Nothing Then "skip the next three lines of code and display a message box"" without exiting the sub? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright so just to make it clear and complete I will post the full code that worked for my situation, which was:
I wanted to make a macro that would be able to automatically find a certain column based on its name, then insert another column next to that one, select that new column and fill it with a formula, while automatically detecting when to stop (in term of number of rows).
The challenge for me was to find a way to indicate several directions in vba while never using coordinates like "A2" or "F67".

Thanks a lot to tigeravatar for his very valuable help in solving that problem!
Below is the code I will be using (except if anyone finds something simpler of course):

```
Sub Test_New_Macro()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngLocation As Range
Dim rngNewCol As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rngLocation = ws.Rows(1).Find("Location - City")
If rngLocation Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
rngLocation.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
Set rngNewCol = rngLocation.Offset(, 1)
lRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Range("A1"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row - 1
rngNewCol.Value = "Geographic Area"
With rngNewCol.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lRow)
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Formula = "Myformula"
End With
```

I made a few changes to tigeravatar's code:
on line 15:

```
With rngNewCol.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lRow)
```

I changed (, 1) to (1, 0). Otherwise the macro would fill both the column's header and the next column with the formula.
Also, I added several lines:
EDIT: thanks tigeravatar for that too!

```
    .NumberFormat = "General"
```

Just before filling the column with the formula because otherwise the formula would appear as text (because the cells were formatted as text from the beginning).
I might be declaring victory too soon, but after several tests it seems to work just fine!

Thanks again tigeravatar you have been very helpful!

EDIT: tigeravatar posted a simpler way to make the number format General while I was posting this answer. I edited my answer with the code he posted.